# Mongoid connecting to localhost at 27017 even after specifying different address in mongoid.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, yaml

I'm running a rails application on EC2, and I'm using mongoHQ as DBMS. I've specified following values in mongoid.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
host: staff.mongohq.com
port: 10082
username: CodeMaster123
password: 00000000

development:
<<: *defaults
database: app-development

test:
<<: *defaults
database: app-box-test
```

But when I execute `rails s` it throws an error saying

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongo-1.4.0/lib/mongo/connection.rb:
526:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017(Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
```

Is there a way to check whether mongoid is reading mongoid.yml?

Edit:

If I use wrong port number then it show an error

```
Failed to connect to a master node at spd.mongohq.com:10092 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
```

It means that it ignore the the connection options specified in mongoid.yml and connects to localhost:27017. Why is it happening?

Comment: i have exactly the same problem with rails 3.2.1.. i'm not using heroku

Comment: I'm hoping this is a silly question, but just in case - is that your real password?

Comment: thanks for bringing it to my attension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two files specifying DBMS details, I edited them and my application worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try writing the full options under development: in yaml file rather then using pointers? I believe there has been bugs in this departement.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid does not seem to support correctly YAML loading in its current public version (2.3.4). You can take a look at this commit for more details:
[Refactor options and env into their own modules](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/commit/96961bc0edf44ef9489ac12837389ff1880db642)

Put the following in your Gemfile to benefit from this recent commit (for me under Sinatra):

```
gem 'mongoid', :git => "https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git"
```